# Semidirect Products in Category Theory?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

Here is a quote from the wikipedia entry on semidirect products of groups:

> "There are also far-reaching generalisations in category theory. They show how to construct fibred categories from indexed categories. This is an abstract form of the outer semidirect product construction."

**Do you know any reference for this general construction?**

I know that every "indexed category" $F : C^{op} \to \mathrm{Cat}$ gives rise to a fibration $E \to C$, namely that fibration whose $x$-fiber is precisely $F(x)$, **but is this really meant here?**

I don't see the connection with semi-direct products yet.

Comment: Maybe I'm oversimplifying here, but the semidirect products of groups correspond to right-invertible morphisms: in a short exact sequence $$0 \to A \to B \stackrel{p}{\to} C \to 0$$ $B \cong A \rtimes_\varphi C$ iff $p: B \to C$ is right-invertible (i.e. it has a section).

Comment: Yes but the quote goes into another direction.

Comment: Why don't you react at all to the very long answer you got?

Comment: Sorry, I've just seen it now. Am I supposed to look here every day? Did you also give the downvote because of that?

Comment: "Am I supposed to look here every day?" No. But you asked 3 questions since this answer was posted. I posted a comment and you posted yet another question after that comment. Hence the downvote, hoping that you will look what happened. Obviously it worked. I removed the downvote by the way.

Comment: Oh my god. Recently the stats page has become more confusing than before. And often I work in various problems simultanously. There is no reason for you to get me doing this in a specific order. Good answers last forever, there is no reason why I have to read and check them immediately.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A semidirect product of two groups $H$ and $N$ is the same as a group
homomorphism $\varphi: H\rightarrow \mathrm{Aut}(N)$ i.e. an action of
$H$ on $N$. Groupies usually drop the $\varphi$ from the notation and
simply write $n^h$ instead of $n^{\varphi h}$. The resulting multiplication
on $H\times N$ is then given by $(h,n)(k,m) = (hk,n^km)$.

Likewise a semidirect product of two monoids $H$ and $N$ is the same as a
monoid homomorphism $\varphi: H\rightarrow \mathrm{End}(N)$. The multiplication
is given in the same way.

Now consider a functor $F: C\rightarrow \mathrm{Cat}$ (I ignore dualization,
so this correspond to an op-fibration) and suppose that

(1) $C$ is a monoid (i.e. has exactly one object $*$)

(2) The category $F(*)$ is also a monoid.

Because an endofunctor on $F(*)$ is the same as a monoid homomorphism, this
is the same as giving a monoid homomorphism from $C$ to $\mathrm{End}(F(*))$.

In fact, if you go through the Grothendieck construction for the corresponding
op-fibration, you will produce exactly the above multipilcation. The similarity
is also visible in the general case if you view $F: C\rightarrow \mathrm{Cat}$
as a category action of $C$, drop the $F$ from the notation and write
$uf$ instead of $F(f)u$ for $f:c\rightarrow c'$ and $u\in F(c)$:

For $c,c',c''\in C$, $x\in F(c)$, $x'\in F(c')$, $x''\in F(c'')$,
$f:c\rightarrow c'$, $u:F(f)x\rightarrow x'$,
$g:c'\rightarrow c''$, $u:F(g)x'\rightarrow x''$ consider the maps
$(f,u):(c,x)\rightarrow (c',x')$ and $(g,v):(c',x')\rightarrow (c'',x'')$
in the Grothendieck construction. If we write composition of maps from
left to right and apply the above mentioned notational simplification, then
the composition of $(f,u)$ and $(g,v)$ can be written as $(fg,(ug)v)$
where $(xf)g$ is the composite
$$xfg \stackrel{ug}{\rightarrow} x'g \stackrel{v}{\rightarrow} x''$$

There is also a very nice description in Section 12.2 ("The Grothendieck construction") of
[Barr/Wells: Category Theory for Computing Science](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/22/tr22.pdf).